# .isdigit index out of range python

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing

This is a simpler version of a code I am using to differentiate a function, but it demonstrates the problem. I get the 'listindex out of range' error. It only occurs when I include the .isdigit section. Any help is much appreciated!

```
l='1bcd'
b=list(l)
for i in range (0,len(b)): 

    if b[i].isdigit:
        if i==0:
            if b[i+1]=='b':

                del b[i]
print b
```

Comment: Your isn't pythonic at all. You should use directly your list for make a loop not a list of its indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are altering the length of `b`; you delete the first character. Your `range()` however will still continue and you end up with `i = 3` applied to a `b` with only indices `0`, `1`, and `2`.

You could use a `while` loop instead:

```
i = 0
while i < len(b) - 1:
    if b[i].isdigit() and b[i + 1] == 'b':
        del b[i]
    else:
        b += 1
```

I removed the `i == 0` test as that no longer applies.

Note that your `isdigit` test is *always* true because you are not *calling* it.

Comment: But i only attempt to do that when i==0, so i+1 would be 1 which is still within the length of the list?